# The callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted changes when running open API Action Flow from Process Builder

Tags: rest-api, process-builder

I have an Auto Launched Flow that passes contact details through an Open Api action. This Flow works when using the Debug. BUT when coupled with a Process builder that triggers on Contact where status or two other check boxes are changed on save I get this error -

"Error element API_V6 (FlowActionCall).
Callout failed: The callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted changes related to a process, flow, or Apex operation. Commit or roll back the work, and then try again. For more information, contact your Salesforce admin.

---

Flow Details
Flow API Name: Customer_Portal_Contact
Type: Autolaunched Flow
Version: 1
Status: Active
Org: Vertel (00D1m0000008lFz)
Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Customer Portal Contact 11/03/2021 3:48 PM
Current User: Michael Santry (0057F000002WvHh)
Start time: 11/03/2021 3:48 PM
Duration: 1 seconds
How the Interview Started
Michael Santry (0057F000002WvHh) started the flow interview.
API Version for Running the Flow: 51
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
recordId = 0031m00000BXhm5AAD
GET RECORDS: getContactDetails
Find all Contact records where:
Id Equals {!recordId} (0031m00000BXhm5AAD)
Store the values of these fields in getContactDetails: Email, AccountId, Permission_to_Market__c, Portal_Access__c, Portal_Power_Access__c, Phone, FirstName, Title, status__c, Id, LastName
Result
Successfully found records.
GET RECORDS: getAccountDetails
Find all Account records where:
Id Equals {!getContactDetails.Account.Id} (0017F00001DxJWcQAN)
Store the values of these fields in getAccountDetails: Id, Account_ID__c, Status__c, Name
Result
Successfully found records.
ASSIGNMENT: Assignment_V3
{!Body_V6.AccountId} Equals {!getAccountDetails.Account_ID__c}
{!Body_V6.AccountName} Equals {!getAccountDetails.Name}
{!Body_V6.AccountStatus} Equals {!getAccountDetails.Status__c}
{!Body_V6.AccountRecID} Equals {!getAccountDetails.Id}
{!Body_V6.ContactRecID} Equals {!getContactDetails.Id}
{!Body_V6.JobTitle} Equals {!getContactDetails.Title}
{!Body_V6.PermissionToMarket} Equals {!getContactDetails.Permission_to_Market__c}
{!Body_V6.PhoneNumber} Equals {!getContactDetails.Phone}
{!Body_V6.PortalUser} Equals {!getContactDetails.Portal_Access__c}
{!Body_V6.SuperUser} Equals {!getContactDetails.Portal_Power_Access__c}
{!Body_V6.UserStatus} Equals {!getContactDetails.status__c}
{!Body_V6.Email} Equals {!getContactDetails.Email}
{!Body_V6.FirstName} Equals {!getContactDetails.FirstName}
{!Body_V6.LastName} Equals {!getContactDetails.LastName}
Result
{!Body_V6.PhoneNumber} = "6546546546"
{!Body_V6.LastName} = "lname"
{!Body_V6.FirstName} = "fname"
{!Body_V6.PortalUser} = "false"
{!Body_V6.UserStatus} = "Active"
{!Body_V6.AccountId} = "6379"
{!Body_V6.AccountRecID} = "0017F00001DxJWcQAN"
{!Body_V6.PermissionToMarket} = "null"
{!Body_V6.AccountStatus} = "Active"
{!Body_V6.AccountName} = "accountName"
{!Body_V6.Email} = "email@email.com"
{!Body_V6.SuperUser} = "true"
{!Body_V6.JobTitle} = "null"
{!Body_V6.ContactRecID} = "0031m00000BXhm5AAD"
COPYOFCREATEPORTALUSERV6.POSTAPICREATEUSER (EXTERNAL SERVICES): API_V6
Inputs:
body = {!Body_V6} (CopyOfCreatePortalUserV6_Model0 : { "UserStatus" : "Active", "SuperUser" : "true", "PortalUser" : "false", "PhoneNumber" : "6546546546", "LastName" : "lname", "FirstName" : "fname", "Email" : "email@email.com", "ContactRecID" : "0031m00000BXhm5AAD", "AccountStatus" : "Active", "AccountRecID" : "0017F00001DxJWcQAN", "AccountName" : "Accountname", "AccountId" : "6379" })

---

Error Occurred: Callout failed: The callout was unsuccessful because of pending uncommitted changes related to a process, flow, or Apex operation. Commit or roll back the work, and then try again. For more information, contact your Salesforce admin.
"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform a callout immediately after an insert  / update / delete operation (a DML action).  Salesforce considers the callout to be within the same transaction as the DML action, and the system architecture will not allow this.

You have to use a scheduled action in your process builder to perform the callout.  Scheduled (aka asynchronous) actions are treated as separate transactions from the immediate transaction that triggers the process builder.